# Stripe : No card attached to customer after a checkout session payment

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe with PHP, I want to create subscription to customer after a payment made with Stripe Checkout Session.

But, the problem is that when we do a one shot payment with Stripe Checkout Session, Stripe does not attach the source (Credit card) to the customer, and when I try to subscribe this customer to a plan, Stripe return me the error :
`This customer has no attached payment source or default payment method.`

I don't understand why Stripe don't attach the card to the customer with one shot payment because Stripe do it when we use a Checkout Session with Subscription.

How I create checkout session :

```php
$checkout_session = Session::create([
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'mode' => 'payment',
    'customer' => 'cus_xxxxxxxx',
    'line_items' => [[
        'price' => 'price_xxxxx', // Oneshot payment
        'quantity' => 1,
    ]]
]);
```

How I try to subscribe customer (After successful payment) :

```php
$subscription = Subscription::create([
    'customer' => 'cus_xxxxxxxx',
    'items' => [
        ['price' => 'price_XXXXXXX'] // Recurrent payment
    ],
    'trial_from_plan' => true,
]);
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accepting a one-time payment with Checkout, it won't create a Customer or save card details by default. What you have to do is configure Checkout to do this for you during the payment. This is covered in their documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/how-checkout-works#save).

What you need to do is set the `payment_intent_data[setup_future_usage]` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-setup_future_usage) like this:

```
$checkout_session = Session::create([
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'customer' => 'cus_xxxxxxxx',
  'line_items' => [[
    'price' => 'price_xxxxx', // Oneshot payment
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
  'payment_intent_data' => [
    'setup_future_usage' => 'off_session',
  ]
]);
```

After that, you will have a Customer `cus_123` and a PaymentMethod `pm_123` that you can re-use. That PaymentMethod will not be the default one though so you need to make sure that you pass its id in the `default_payment_method` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-default_payment_method) when you create the Subscription like this:

```
$subscription = Subscription::create([
  'customer' => 'cus_xxxxxxxx',
  'items' => [
    ['price' => 'price_XXXXXXX'] // Recurrent payment
  ],
  'trial_from_plan' => true,
  'default_payment_method' => 'pm_12345',
]);
```

Also note that you can start a Subscription directly from Checkout as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart).